# Probability 20 defective items

Tags: probability-theory

A box contains 20 items of which 25% are defective. 3 items are randomly selected one after another without replacement. Let X be the number of defectives in the 3 selected items. 
a). Find the probability that the first item selected is defective. 
b). After selecting a defective item on the first selection, what is the probability that the 2nd item is defective?
c). Is X a binomial random variable? If yes, why.

Comment: I let X be 1 for the first item chosen to be defective P(X=1) and then p(X=2) for part b

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If the first item selected is defective, then you have 19 items left out of which 4 are defective. Also, a binomial distribution assumes that all 3 chosen items have the same probability of being defective, independent of one another. Is this true if you select without replacement? For example, is the distribution binomial if you choose 6 items since there are only 5 defective ones?

Answer (score 1):

Hypergeometric / conditional-hypergeometric distribution for the proper use. It can be constructed through summing binomial distributions but that's a little sketchy...

We know that 25% of the 20 items are defective. This means that 5/20 are defective.

a) 25%
b) 4/19
c) Hypergeometric distribution

Comment: For part a though, being that the sample being 3 would that change it from 25%, because it seems 25% is for the overall not just the 3 being randomly chosen.

Comment: the probability of the FIRST item being selected having some characteristic is the same as the distribution for the overall sample. 

imagine having 99 good apples and 1 bad apple. 1% of them are bad apples. On the very first draw the probability is 1/100. This doesn't matter if there is or is not replacement since we're only looking at the first draw. 

You were adding additional complexity. The question for A is equivalent to simply choosing 1 item at random.